# Missing characters in WebBrowser printout

Tags: c#, html, wpf, printing

I have a `WPF` application that uses the `WebBrowser` control in order to print `html` documents.
My problem is that from *time to time* some of the characters are missing from the generated documents.
I tried to replace the printer and cables and I also validated the `html` markup [here](https://validator.w3.org/).
This is how I generate the printing:

```
public static class HtmlPrint
{
    public static void Print(string html, string documentTitle)
    {
        var wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser { DocumentText = html };
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = ((System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender);

        wb.Print();
        wb.Dispose();
    }
}
```

HTML sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Items report</title>
<style type='text/css'>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table.gridtable {
        font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #666666;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

        table.gridtable th {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666666;
            background-color: #dedede;
        }

        table.gridtable td {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666666;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            /*white-space:nowrap*/
        }
</style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<h3>15/12/2015 09:22:17</h3>
<h3>Items for station: 1</h3>
<br />
<table class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AD393</td>
        <td>06957TO_GRE_S</td>
        <td>Green shirt</td>
        <td>GREEN-GRAY</td>
        <td>S(36)</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>AD-37-5<br />AD-38-3<br />AD-38-5<br />AD-39-0<br />AD-39-3<br />AD-39-5<br />BC-38-1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>CA183</td>
        <td>A100000000464</td>
        <td>White golf shirt</td>
        <td>WHITE</td>
        <td>XS/S (34-36)</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>AI-25-1<br />AK-25-1<br />AK-36-6<br />AK-37-6<br />AL-24-1<br />AL-25-1<br />CA-18-3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?
**UPDATE**
I've tried using the `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` as follows but it prints empty pages:

```
public static void Print(string html)
    {
        /*
        html is the actual HTML data e.g. 
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="he-IL" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
            ...
        */
        try
        {
            var wb = new System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser();
            wb.LoadCompleted += Wb_LoadCompleted; //never called
            wb.Loaded += Wb_Loaded; //never called

            wb.NavigateToString(html);
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = wb.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
            doc.execCommand("Print", true, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //no exception raised
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this HTML example not print correctly? Are the missing characters not the standard a-z, A-Z or 0-9 characters?

Comment: this HTML doesn't print correctly, although it's really inconsistent. missing chars are standard letters  and numbers (a-z, A-Z and 0-9)

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` class instead of `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`?

Comment: It's what [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print.aspx) article suggests. I'll have a look at the `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` option...

Comment: That article is specifically for WinForms tho'. I've found that mixing WPF and WinForms doesn't work particularly well - to print from the WPF control, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298969/printing-the-contents-of-a-wpf-webbrowser

Comment: @toadflakz Please see my update